# How to make redirect from one group of URLs to another?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I need to make redirect in the following way:

from:
`site.ru/blog/article_slug`
to:
`site.ru/news/article_slug`

I tried to use it, but it doesn't work fine (displays 404 error page):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(\/blog\/)(\S+)$
RewriteRule /news\/%3 [R=301,L]
```

Full htaccess file (mod_rewrite part):

```
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Please describe what behaviour do you get from the rules you used and how it is different from what you expect. "doesn't work fine" is not specific enough.

Comment: It displays 404 error page

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this with HTML or Javascript? With HTML you would only need to include the meta tag: `<meta http-equid="refresh" content="0"; URL ='http://site.ru/news/article_slug.com />` in the head of site.ru/blog/article_slug. You could also use Javascript to do this: `window.location = "http://site.ru/news/article_slug.com"`

Comment: No, I cannot use it. It should be made by htaccess using mod_rewrite. Your variant may be used in static sites. May be I misunderstood you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

On `RewriteBase` please put your actual directory where you are applying rule if it is root leave it like above rule.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now it redirects me on: site.com/var/www/html/public/news/Skype-for-Business. It pastes full file system path

Comment: I already have constructions you provided. Above in question body I posted full .htaccess. So where exactly am I supposed to write your constructions?

Comment: .htaccess file is located in "var/www/html/public"

Comment: Try this where your index file resides like in public which will be root of your directory.